# How to get stats for Github PRs code reviews

Tags: github

I want to get a list of people who did some PR code reviews in my organization in the past month. Also how many code reviews were done by each one of them. It would also be helpful if I can know how many comments each person made. Is there a way to get these stats in UI without doing any code changes?

Comment: You probably need to use [the GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options including: the [Github API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/pulls/reviews?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-reviews-on-a-pull-request) or a proprietary service like [PR Stats](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/pull-request-stats).

With the `Github API` you can use the following:

```
curl \
-H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>"\
-H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/pulls/PULL_NUMBER/reviews
```

With `PR Stats` you'll need to create a Github Action to include a table of PR stats in each PR you create within Github.